# pandas, HDFstore and memory usage through load/unload cycles

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I happily use pandas to store and manipulate experimental data. Usually, I choose HDF format (which I don't master) via `pd.HDFstore` to save stuff.

My dataframes got bigger and bigger and some *economy in memory* is needed.

I read some of the guides linked in related questions, although I cannot achieve a sustainable memory consumption, e.g. in the following typical task of mine:

```
. load some `df` in memory (scale size is 10GB)
. do business with some other preloaded `df`
. unload
. repeat
```

Apparently I keep on failing in the unloading stage.

---

**Hence, I would like you to consider the following experiments.**

*(From fresh started kernel (in ipython notebook, if that matters))*

```
import pandas as pd

for idx in range(6):
    print idx
    store = pd.HDFStore('detection_DB_N.h5')
    detection_DB = store['detection_DB']
    store.close()

    del detection_DB
```

stats (from `top`):

```
. memory used by first iteration ~8GB
. memory used at the end of execution ~10GB (6 cycles)
```

Then, in the same kernel, I run

```
for idx in range(6):
    print idx
    store = pd.HDFStore('detection_DB_N.h5')
    detection_DB = store['detection_DB']
    store.close()

    #del detection_DB  #SAME AS BEFORE, BUT I DON'T del
```

stats:

```
. memory used at the end of execution ~15GB
```

Calling a `del detection_DB` doesn't make any difference in memory (CPU usage goes high for some 5sec).

Analogusly, calling

```
 import gc 
 gc.collect()
```

doesn't make any relevant difference.

I add, for what is worth, that repeating the previous calls, I arrived to have ~20GB occupied (and no loaded object to play with).

---

Can anyone shed some light?

How can I achieve ~0GB (or so) occupied after `del`?

Comment: you have to turn off ipython caching which is kind of hard, e.g. ``_``, ``__`` are being referenced to the last commands called, which causes the memory not to be garbage collected. run in a vanilla python session, and print out the memory after every cycle. also you have to understand that python doesn't return memory to the os, so even though its empty it will still show up. you in effect get peak memory.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for your answer. It's pretty illuminating.
 Any suggestion for workarounds? I would like not to occupy 35GB out of my (shared-with-others) 64GB and maybe use just 10.
Thanks.

Comment: don't hold onto the refernces; use the data and then del (and gc in the same loop). use chunking. do in separate processes (this it eh best) and you can read-process-write_to_a_new_hdf_always then combine results